# Data structure used for a buffer

Tags: data-structures, buffer

I attended a developer interview recently and I was asked the following question: 
I have a server that can handle 20 requests. Which data structure is used to model this? What will happen if thee are more than 20 requests? i.e., What will you do in case of buffer overflow? 
I am not from CS background. I am transitioning from a different field. I am self taught in programming and DSA. So I would like to know the answers for these questions. Thanking in advance!

Comment: Do you mean 20 concurrent requests? Have you heard of a [queue](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/queue-data-structure/).

Comment: Yes. Twenty concurrent requests. I have heard of a queue. I have implemented a queue in python.

Comment: And also please tell me what to do if there are simultaneous requests and not concurrent ones.

Comment: Concurrent and simultaneous are synonyms.

Comment: Oh ok. I did not know that. So what should I do if I get more than 20 requests. I think it is called buffer overflow. How to rectify it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Regarding a server that can handle 20 simultaneous requests:

Your question indicates that you are not yet thinking about this is in a reasonable way and are probably quite far from understanding how it works.  No problem -- it just means that maybe you have more to learn than you expect.

To help you along, I will write you the correct answer, full of terms you can google for:

When a client attempts to connect to your server, the kernel puts his request in to a 'listen queue' attached to your server's listening 'socket'.

When your server is ready to service a request, it 'accepts' a connection from the listening socket, which creates a new socket for the communication between the client and server, and the server then processes the request.

If your server can handle 20 simultaneous requests, it typically means that it can have up to 20 threads processing connections at the same time.  That is usually accomplished by using a 'thread pool' of limited size.  When a thread in the pool is available, it gets a new connection from the listening socket (might have to wait for one), and processes it, and it is only the fact that there are at most 20 of these threads that limits the number of request you will handle simultaneously.  (nothing to do with a buffer of any kind, really)

If the server is already processing 20 simultaneous requests when a new one comes in, then the client's request will wait in the socket listen queue until the server eventually picks it up, or it will timeout and fail if it has been waiting too long.

There is also a limit (the TCP backlog) on the number of connection requests that can be waiting in the listen queue.  If a connection request comes in when the listen queue is full, it is immediately rejected.  If you want your server to handle 20 simultaneous requests, then the listen queue should have length at least 20 in case 20 requests arrive at the same time -- they will all get queued until your server picks them up.

Comment: Ok! Thanks. This is a very clear explanation. A great answer! I got the picture. I got another doubt now. What exactly is buffer then and buffer overflow? Where is it used?

Comment: @Laxman a buffer is just an area of memory used to transfer data from one part of the program  or system to another. A buffer overflow is a programming error that mistakenly writes outside the buffer -- like causing 200 bytes to be written into a 100 byte space.  The result can be that critical parts of data structures get overwritten with garbage

Comment: Ok! Got it! Thank you.